# Why the variable is being shared in some Classes but not others?

Tags: python

I have  an issue where my Classes keep creating new DB connections, and I'm trying to understand what am I doing wrong... this is my structure:

```
index.py
 |_ a/const.py    ( not a Class, just several functions )
      db = None

      def get_connection():
         global db

         if not db:    
           db = created_new_connection()
           print "New connection has been created"
         else:
           print "Connection already exists"

         return db

 |_ a/group.py   ( import const, Class )
 |_ a/user.py    ( import const, Class )
```

"index.py" imports "const" and another module that later uses "group" and "user"

When I run index.py, I get:

```
group.py "New connection has been created"
user.py "New connection has been created"
```

So for the test, I tried creating the connection in the "index.py" instead, but now I get:

```
index.py "New connection has been created"
group.py run func1() "Connection already exists"
group.py run func2() "Connection already exists"
user.py "New connection has been created"
```

Now - I'm confused. both "group" and "user" are written almost the exact same way. how is it that when "group" run "get_connection()" it works as expected ( already exists ) and later when "user" run "get_connection()" it creates a new connection ....

What's interesting ( to me ) is that when I created files ( a,b,c,d ) in the same directories ( to keep structure ) and imported "c.py" in all files, then "a" created the connection, but "b and d" did not create a new connection, they used the one that is still open.... ( which is what I expect )

Any ideas ? thanks in advance ...

Comment: `get_connection` shouldn't work under any conditions; `db` is local to `get_connection`, so the `if not db` test should raise an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: Sorry but I left that out, I am already using "global db", this is why in "group.py" it works ... it also work if inside the group.py there's another function that call get_connection() - it will say "already exists"

Comment: You may be having problems with your import path, causing the same file to be imported multiple times as highly similar yet distinct modules.

Comment: You 100% right ... I just threw a "print" in const.py and I see it in the same amount as I see the connections being opened. I'll check it - thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to this:

```
def get_connection():
    global db

    if not db:    
        db = created_new_connection()
        print "New connection has been created"
    else:
        print "Connection already exists"

    return db
```

If you have this, the only possibility for the function to enter the first block for the second time is that `created_new_connection()` function returns something that evaluates to `False` (e.g. `None` or an empty `str`, or an empty `list`, ...).

Alternatively, you may experience a situation when Python loads a module twice, as explained [here](http://koichitamura.blogspot.com/2009/07/ill-show-you-case-where-one-file.html): basically if you import a module using different relative paths Python will treat them as different modules, and load them twice. A suggested solution from this blog post is to always load modules using their top-level paths.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the code, I am already doing that ... still doesn't work

Comment: @Ricky Check the link I've provided.

Comment: yes, continuing @user2357112's comment that the modules are loaded twice, from your link I figure out that the issue is a sym-link that I did in order to "from bla import const" ( because they were not in the same directory level ... ), by printing the print const.__name__ I see it instantly ... thank you very much all !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a global variable, you can also consider using a "[Borg](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/)" class. This is the Python alternative to a singleton class.

**database.py**

```
class Database:

    __shared_state = {}
    db = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state

    def get_connection(self):

        if not self.db:
            self.db = self.create_new_connection()
            print "New connection has been created"
        else:
            print "Connection already exists"

        return self.db

    def create_new_connection(self):
        # create and return new connection
```

Then import this class like `from database import Database` and get your connection with `Database().get_connection()`.

Comment: Not working ... in general I'm not sure how this works ... what makes self.db shared after the first module is done with it and being destroyed?, another thing, have you left this by mistake ( db = None )  or it suppose to have a purpose ?

Comment: Why would it be destroyed? In a python process, a module is imported only once (even when you import it from multiple other modules) and the state in that module is maintained. I put `db = None` in because otherwise you would get an AttributeError because it wouldn't be defined. Check what BartoszKP says at the end of is answer.

Comment: Yeah .. just the "Borg" link idea is that no matter how I write the code, it makes sure that only one instance of this module is loaded twice .. I thought it's a better way to do it ...

Comment: A module is always loaded once only (except when python thinks it are different modules as described by BartoszKP at the end of his answer...). The Borg pattern makes sure that the state of the class is the same for every instance you create.